# SSL certificate - basic or wildcard question

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I am not sure if I need a basic or wildcard certificate and how many.
1) I assume 1 certificate goes in 1 server - so if I have 2 web servers then i need 2 certificates?

2) From what I read wildcard is only needed for subdomains. But what about if i have the same main domain but just use subdomains for multilanguage? like my site is say www.xxx.com and when someone is viewing it in british english i change it to:  uk-eng.xxx.com

In the above case will a basic certificate work or is this a wildcard?

Comment: Do you have more than one common name (CN) i.e foo.yourdomain.com and bar.yourdomain.com?  If so, you can get 2 ssl certs or 1 wildcard cert and put it on both machines.

Comment: No. Same name, just the multilang subdoamins.

Comment: You might want to consider making the language on the other end of the URL; if that is not an option, I would think a wildcard cert would be appropriate, unless you know there's only going to be 2 servers and it's more cost-effective to get 2 certs.  Wildcard certs are usually more expensive.

Comment: Yes these are more expensive. What a rip off. Anyways, thanks, wildcard it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two web servers usually have different host names (if it's not a cluster). So you need protect both host names.

An HTTP certificate protects the host name, so a certificate for "www.xxx.com" is only for this domain. Wildcard allows subdomains, i.e. "*.xxx.com" allows all names e.g. "www.xxx.com" and "uk-eng.xxx.com", but more expencive, however you can use the same certificate on several servers.

Answer (score 0):

One certificate is *usually* needed per domain, not per server (one cert can cover more than one domain, hence "usually"). For multiple subdomains you would need a wildcard certificate.

If you are not sure, the best idea is to contact CA's support and ask them what they can offer you. Different CAs have different offers for cases like yours.

JFYI: Standard single-domain certificate is usually issued for "domain.com" and "www.domain.com" (so it covers a domain and one of it's subdomains).